# Taylor approximation with 2 variables, not sure how to solve this

Tags: taylor-expansion, linearization

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> Let $f(x,y)=ay+sin(bx)+c$. Evaluate the Taylor polynomial at $P(0,0)$ and find the values for $a$, $b$ and $c$ if $P(x,y)=-1+2x-y$

I do know the linearization formula, but it requires me to use the value of $f$ at the given point. However, since there are 3 unknown constants, I don't know how to work this out...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: For your older questions: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). - 8/33 accepted answers is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *linear* Taylor-Polynomial of $f$ with respect to $(0,0)$ is given by:

$$f(x,y) \approx P(x,y;(0,0))= f(0,0) + f'_x(0,0)(x-0) + f'_y(0,0)(y-0)$$

Can you take it from here? 
The spoiler contains the next step - try to do it yourself, first.

> $$P(x,y) = [c] + [b\cos(b0)x] + [ay] = c + bx + ay\overset{!}{=}-1+2x-y$$

Comment: Thank you :) What I'm stuck with is, how do you relate $c$ with $f(0,0)$? I know the function and the linearization have the same value at the evaluated point, so I got $-1 + [b\cos(b0)x] + [ay]$ and I got that $-1$ from evaluating the given $P(x,y)$ at the given $(0,0)$. But how can I say that "c = -1"?

Comment: $c=f(0, 0)=P(0, 0) = -1$. This should follow directly from the associativity of equality ($a=b$ and $b=c$ implies $a=c$).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I understand that $f(0, 0)=P(0, 0)$. What I don't get is why those two are the same as $c$. Probably a silly question, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: In the spoiler we calculated the general Taylor-Polynomial. This has to be ($\overset{!}{=}$) equal to the polynomial from the Task. It holds: Two polynomials $f(x)=a_0 + a_1x+…$ and $g(x)=b_0 + b_1x+ …$ are equal if their coefficients are equal: $$f=g ⇔ a_0=b_0, a_1=b_1 ...$$ So we can "equate coefficients". (Small remark: This statement is not always correct in the way written here. But for the sake of this answer it is true.)

Answer (score 1):

The second order taylor polynomial of $f(x, y)$ at $(0, 0)$ is $$f_{approx}(x, y) = c + b\cos(bx_0)x+ay+0xy = c+bx+ay.$$

But we are given that $f_{approx}(x, y) = -1+2x-y$, so we set the expressions equal to solve for $a, b,$ and $c$. This yields:

$$-1+2x-y=c+bx+ay\\\implies a = -1, b = 2, c = -1.$$